# Trouble using string and regex in .withText API in TestCafe

Tags: regex, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm trying to use text and regex both in the `.withText()` to verify one of my tests. Here is what I wish to accomplish:

```
Selector('div').withText(`Are you sure you want to delete this field? It is currently used for 1 people. This action cannot be undone.`);
```

In the above code, I have a variable `1 people` it could be `2 people`, etc. I need a way so that it accepts the integers (like `1` or `2` etc). I tried the thing below and some other as well but the problem is TestCafe treats that regex as a text:

```
Selector('div').withText(`Are you sure you want to delete this field\? It is currently used for [0-9] people. This action cannot be undone.`);
```

Error:

```
Cannot obtain information about the node because the specified selector does not match any node in the DOM tree.

   > | Selector('div')
     |   .withText(`Are you sure you want to delete this field\? It is currently used for [0-9] people. This action cannot be undone.`)
```

How do I write a selector which can accommodate both string and regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please enclose your pattern in slashes to create [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and then put it into the TestCafe [`withText`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/functional-style-selectors.html#withtext) method. The following code should work for your case:

```js
Selector('div')
    .withText(/Are you sure you want to delete this field\? It is currently used for [1-9] people\. This action cannot be undone\./);
```